# Gracefully stop docker container when shutting down Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I delete a GCE VM I need my docker container to get stopped gracefully before the VM shuts down.

I am using Compute Engine Container Optimized OS (COS) and would expect my containers to be managed properly, but this is not what I am experiencing.

I tried a shutdown-script calling `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` but it doesn't make a difference at all. I can see it runs, but it seems the container is already gone by then.

I've tried trapping SIGTERM in my application. In the VM it's not trapping the signal, but on my local machine it does.

I am a bit lost and don't know what else to try. Any idea?

Comment: Does the command you listed work fine on local environment? If not, make sure you are not using "shell form" CMD or ENTRYPOINT instruction, it will swallow the SIGTERM. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Locally, stopping the container with `docker stop` makes the SIGTERM get trapped in my application, yes. That's what makes me say the Container Optimised OS does not seem to manage container shutdown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Stopping Docker Containers Gracefully](https://akomljen.com/stopping-docker-containers-gracefully/) and also [Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Comment: Good read, but not the problem I have. I am not running a script, but starting my application directly.

Comment: @Robin. Using a bash script to start the process is just a trick to force it to use PID1, as when you start your app with exec in your script, then things look different. Using exec causes the process to take over the current process, which means your script no longer runs. It won’t even execute the rest of the script.

If you are running your application directly you have to send the signal to safely stop it. Check this article that explains  it better than me

Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers
https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/